# Parametrized classes in java clarification

Tags: java

I have a following class declaration

```
public class A extends B<List<Pair<String, String>>>{
   ...
}
```

I wanted to know what does `<List<Pair<String, String>>>` is used for? What purpose does it solve??

Comment: It is the type argument for the paremeterized type `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The B class is parametrized, and it's parameter here a List of Pairs of 2 strings